# java script customize dialog box

Tags: javascript, css

I want to show a dialog box in center and remove the "the host name says..."
and customize it with css.

```
function myFunction() {
alert("Record Save");
}
```

thanx in advance

Comment: If you are using Bootstrap, you can use Bootstrap modals to show a dialog box. Refer [here](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp)

Comment: You're looking for what's called a modal.

Comment: thnx for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't customize a javascript alert, it is 100% handled by the browser. What you have to do is create your own function for alerts.

So you'd have something like:

```
// CSS
.myAlert {
    position: fixed;
    width: 6cm;
    height: 6cm;
    top: calc(50% - 3cm);
    left: calc(50% - 3 cm);
    display: none;
}
.active {
    display: block;
}
// Javascript + jQuery
function myAlert() {
    $('#myAlertBox').toggleClass('active');
}
// HTML
<div id="myAlertBox">Hello!</div>
```